# Is it advisable to use a URL link shortening service when writing an academic article?

Tags: online-resource, citations

Is it OK to present a URL using a link shortening service such as bit.ly? The reason I'm asking is that I think it's a lot easier to enter this URL (e.g., if you read it in a paper) as opposed to full URL. Or is this a bad idea?

Comment: you mean when writing a paper ?

Comment: In some countries, such shortened URLs are blocked (all of them, regardless of what they link to).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson whoa, did not know that, thanks!

Comment: Many Universities will help you forward links such as university.org/YourLink and that may simplify things.

Comment: @bobthejoe Maybe you are not with a university or at least (VERY likely!) the university doesn't offer such a link? David Ketcherson: Considering that I publish in a country where I know such a short-URL is not blocked, can't I ignore that? I mean I live here, I know that! I don't want / won't consider Cuba, Iran and North Korea in my URL service selection. Further, the www, political and IT-security stances constantly change, so any URL/services could be blocked, couldn't it?

Comment: @grunwald2.0: It's not about where *you* as the author live, it's where possible *readers* live. By using a link shortening service, you may be excluding e.g. Chinese researchers from making sense of your paper.

Comment: Related question on Writers: [Is it fine to use link shorteners for research paper citations?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/3489/11428)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should never offer a link shortener as the only option in an academic paper, for two reasons:

1. It's adding another point of failure: if the shortening service is down, then the link cannot be followed.  This is a particular worry over time, since the service may go out of business.
2. One of the big reasons why link shorteners are so popular is that they keep track of usage statistics.  I'd be offended if I thought an author was using this to monitor when the link was followed, where the people following it were located, etc.

So if you offer a shortened URL, it should only be in addition to the real URL, not in place of it.  However, I'd tend to avoid even that.  It doesn't look professional to me, and I don't think there's much savings for the reader.  (Online papers should have clickable URLs, or at least ones that can be copied and pasted, so this only arises for someone who has a printed copy but no online copy.  That can happen, but it's hardly a major issue.)

Comment: Re #2, in today's Internet tracking is done by any good web server (Google Analytics is often enabled). I don't see shorteners as being worse. However, as one of my students pointed out, you might have a **profile** on the shortener's site (e.g., bit.ly) and others will find out (if you aren't careful to make things private) what other links you have shared.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: That's a good point, but one thing link shorteners can do is give you data on who follows your link to someone else's URL, where you have no access to the server.

Comment: I don't think both point 1 and 2 are substantial. For 1, notorious shorteners like bit.ly or goo.gl will never go down. For 2, one can worry about privacy, but unless you online with anonymous identity, you can't escape from trackers. I think the best reason to avoid them is being not professional. However, since I have seen many professors don't buy their own domains for their websites, I don't think that using shorteners really make that harm.

Comment: Regarding privacy, just because other people are tracking me doesn't mean I should let authors do it too.  As for bit.ly and goo.gl never going down, that may be true now, but it's not guaranteed everywhere (for comparison, tinyurl was blocked in Saudi Aradia) or always (once popular services have been shut down in suboptimal ways after they became less popular, losing data that could have been preserved but wasn't).

Comment: As said above, there are some services such as goo.gl by Google if you are afraid that services such as Bit.ly will go out of business. Google will not go out of business any time soon.

Comment: For point 2), anybody can track you when you are visiting their webpage even without using a URL shortener service. They can record your IP and know your country.  The URL shortener just make it a little bit easier. Besides, I don't see it as a problem. It is actually useful to know if people are interested in your research in my opinion. If you don't want to be tracked on a website, the only way is to not visit the website or use some VPN, etc.

Comment: @Ooker, "notorious shorteners like bit.ly or goo.gl will never go down" and even if they go down, you can track URLs down using search engines such as AltaVista or Lycos which are even less likely to go down.

Comment: @Phil: Anyone can track you when you visit their web site, but URL shorteners allow them to track your visits to third-party sites (if you follow the shortened link).  When I download something from an author's web site, I know they are probably tracking it, but I'd be irritated if an author shortened all links to other people's sites so they could track those too.

Comment: well, I guess we should be fair with the author. If you write a paper, you definitely want to know how many people download it, right? It's the same like you want to know how many people cite it.

Comment: @Ooker: The issue is not the author finding out that I downloaded their paper on the specific occasion of reading the original material with the shortened link. The issue is that the provider of the link shortening service will add that information to a comprehensive profile of my usage behaviour throughout the day that gets extended every time I come across a shortened link from that particular service.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm not sure what you mean. Say the paper is in the bit.ly/123, you go to that link and then later go to the bit.ly/456 which is irrelevant to the paper. What makes you unhappy?

Comment: @Ooker: That whoever is behind bit.ly can gradually compile a profile on the different kinds of topics I may be interested in (not only in research, but also privately).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper i'm not sure if Bitly does collect that data. However, if you really concern about privacy, then this is indeed need to avoid. I would argue that most of us don't need to care that much. Plus, my  is about the collecting of the **author**, which is only mentioned in Anonnymous Mathematician's answer, not the provider.

Comment: @Ooker. I don't control `example.net`. I have no way of knowing that you visited `example.net`. And I certainly have no way of knowing whether you visited it on foot of my recommendation, on foot of someone else's recommendation, as a result of a search, or your own accord. But if I give you a `bit.ly` link which you follow, then I *do* know all of that. This is the difference.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, you should probably also avoid every site that has Google Analytics, as this hypothesis is true of that.  Also, nearly every website you visit has Google Analytics enabled, so the profile of you and what you do is a lot more valuable with them.

Comment: @ThatWebDude: Shouldn't be happening as much with the [Google Analytics opt-out add-on enabled](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=en).

Comment: What if you use official shortenings, like fb.com or wapo.st?

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: It depends!

Long answer: Shortlinks are very useful when space is essential, i.e. when advertising something on twitter. Futhermore, they can often be used for analytics which some of those services offer.

Otherwise, it is often better to provide a full link. It looks more professional and gives more information. Since it is a link, it does not need to be typed in, so it might even be better to show a description instead of the link. The full domain also allows users to decide if they want to follow since it gives additional authenticity when the domain is well known. A lot of shortened urls lead to spam sites, or sites that try to introduce trojans.

Answer (score 7):

A better alternative is to use a [DOI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) if one is available. The providers of a DOI are supposed to ensure that the DOI is always up to date and points to the correct resource and as such a DOI is a better insurance against link rot than the original URL itself.
DOIs are available for most recent papers (at least the ones I know of) as well as data etc. hosted on for example [figshare](http://figshare.com) and [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/). Apart from such resources, DOIs are generally not available and in that case I also recommend using the original URL directly.

Comment: What software support is there for this?

Comment: The issue is not so much software as paying the required fees to the CrossRef organization to register a DOI.  Most publishers now do this routinely for all of their papers, but it's not typical for individuals to be able to register their own DOI's.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's easier to enter. If someone is reading the paper online, it's a click (in the PDF) either way. And as @AM points out, link rot can then get you in two ways instead of one. In fact you should in general be leery about linking to URLs in a paper unless you have some belief that the URL will persist for the life of the paper itself.

Answer (score -2):

I have no problem with shortening a link. In a paper, you won't risk your reputation just to have a spam or contained virus link, therefore people won't need to worry about the security. Also, I don't know if other services have this feature, but you can make an customized link as long as it is unique.

For example, this was my link to my dissertation: [bit.ly/epHIVprotease](http://bit.ly/epHIVprotease). (Need not to follow it, I have pulled it down)

Anyone in my field will immediately understand what it says: **electrostatic potential** of a **HIV protease**. So it's also looked professional, I think.

Comment: So it may be great for a poster (I did it a few times). But not for a paper, for reasons pointed out by Anonymous Mathematician.

Comment: Yeah. It should be good for a printed paper or a poster or a presentation. But if you are worry about the server, you can choose goo.gl. It'll never die :D

Comment: Especially for a poster, I don't see the point. If you want people with mobile devices to directly follow links from your poster, add a QR code to the full URL next to the human-readable full URL rather than going via some third-party shortening service.

Comment: The link to your dissertation is dead.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper QR code is dead

Comment: @JeffE I know, I pull it down

Comment: @Ooker: Where I live, QR codes are commonly found in many public places - public transportation stops (pointing to extended itinerary information), ad posters and displays (pointing to the company website), store fronts (pointing to the online shop or whatever), business cards (replicating the info printed on the card), public wifi hotspots (pointing to the sign up page), etc. In real life, I see nothing that supports your claim.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper may I ask you where you live? I didn't cite my claim because there are many articles on the internet you can find about that.

Comment: @Ooker: I'm in Germany. Before writing my comment, I did a cursory check for the claim, but the first few articles that I could find that did discuss whether QR codes are dead came to a conclusion along the lines of "No, they are not, they are just applied incorrectly and therefore used much less than they could." But even without looking at my location, it is my impression that the use of [QR codes on posters and presentation slides on *international* academic conferences](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49331/use-of-qr-codes-in-academic-publications) is *increasing*.

Comment: Why did you take it down?  The fact that the link is dead undercuts your answer, don't you think?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper there are couple things that I can learn from that link. 1) The disagree answer gets more upvotes. It also encourages to use shorten links 2) To use QR code, one must install the scanning app in their phone, and have to read it in their small screen. 3) As some first commenters say, the use of both QR codes or shorten links are for awkward links which we can easily remember it. If we use shorten links, not only we can avoid the disadvantages of QR code, but also make those awkward links memorizable, as my example points out. So I think it makes more sense to use shorten links.

Comment: @Ooker: 1) That answer may have more upvotes as it directly responds to the question (QR codes on papers) rather than suggesting an alternative, more suitable use, as done in the accepted answer (pointing out QR codes on posters and such). 2) To use a link, one must input the URL on the small on-screen keyboard. To me, that seems more painful than installing a scanning app. 3) QR codes are not about memorizing the URL, but about avoiding its manual input. As such, adding a QR code seems advantageous even when the link is short and memorizeable.

Comment: @JeffE well, actually Google made me to take it down. At that time, I didn't have my own host and domain, so I had to use Google Drive to store it. I stored it in my "professional" account and trying to use my mundane account to access it. It turned out that it didn't allow that due to the conflict of cache. I didn't realize that until it blocked the access to it. Not only that, Bitly doesn't allow you to assign a new link to the old shorten link. Haiz. Anyway, this is a technical problem and I can't do anything.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper 1) You're right. However the accepted answer gets accepted because it answers directly to the **where should QR code be used?** question, while the other one answers the **should QR code be used?** question. I think it would be more suitable in here, not there. 2) I agree too, but keep in mind that the browser can remember the links, while I have never seen an scanning app that can remember the code. This also attributes to point 3)

Comment: @Ooker: The QR scanning app does not need to remember anything. At least the ones I know forward the scanned data to another app to actually *use* the decoded data. For instance, a URL extracted from a scanned code will be opened in the browser (which can then remember the link), wifi access data extracted from a scanned code will be forwarded to the OS (which can then remember the wifi connection), etc.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ah ok then. Well, then we still have point 1 left. Also, I still think that in QR code, your screen is limited

Comment: @Ooker: That's inherent to mobile devices. Whose being suitable for viewing what you link to was my premise from the start, see my first comment: "If you want people with mobile devices to directly follow links from your poster"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that makes sense in poster environment. Ok, I'm with you with this. But in presentations, people tend to have laptops on hands, and it's hard to scan the code on the projector's screen. Also, what if in the poster case, people use tablets? And what if they really need to go home and type the link on their laptops? I use iPhone but don't use Mac so the links can't be shared between two devices. Memorize the links is still handy, right?

Comment: @Ooker: In presentations, many people now have mobile devices. Including tablets. Which usually come with cameras that can be used for scanning QR codes these days, as well. They can manually copy the link from the device, e-mail it to themselves from the device, etc. Indeed, depending on your location in the audience, scanning the QR code on the projected slide may be difficult, but that again just implies the silde should contain both the text URL *and* the QR code. In all, I think this is rather a topic for a new question.